# unable to set date in firefox 57 using selenium version 3.4

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

[date Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv9ji.png) image

unable to set date info past specified date field using `sendKeys` function

Have tried using java script but could not set the value.

update
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5itz.png)

```
driver.findelementBy("//label[text()='Past Specified']/../div[@class='radioHide']//input[1]").sendkeys("01082016");
```

and

```
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript(arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '"+sText+"');",element))
```

please help

Comment: Your code trials and the relevant `HTML` please.

Comment: Updated with HTML and trials

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of code or HTML is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Comment: What is the value of `"xpath"` as in `driver.findelementBy("xpath").sendkeys("01082016");`

Comment: @Debanjan Updated with Xpath

Answer (score 0):

You date format is incorrect. Try the following,

```
driver.findelementBy("//label[text()='Past Specified']/../div[@class='radioHide']//input[1]").sendkeys("01/08/2016");
```

or using javascript

```
String sText="01/08/2016";
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript(arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '"+sText+"');",element))
```

Comment: Tried both the cases. It didn't work. Moreover, Calender is not html based to inspect the elements